# T-SQL CTE apply percentage formula and sum up values for each date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sum, common-table-expression

My database is about cash balance, trades and overnight positions made my users. There are gaps in dates as well.

Using CTE I've selected two tables contain cash and trades balance sum [cashtrade_sum] and positions [pos_sum]. Here is a sample:

```
cashtrade_sum
-------------
2012-01-30  10000.00
2012-03-19  9868.99
2012-03-20  9839.02
2012-03-21  10476.10
2012-03-22  0.00
2012-03-23  10102.81
2012-03-26  10314.76
2012-03-27  11037.40
2012-03-28  9887.76
2012-03-29  9234.28
2012-03-30  8718.67
2012-04-02  8396.65
2012-04-03  0.00
2012-04-12  0.00
2012-05-18  1796.78

pos_sum
-------
2012-03-22  17628.00
2012-03-23  0.00
2012-03-28  373.24
2012-03-29  0.00
2012-04-03  20835.00
2012-04-04  20736.00
2012-04-05  20268.00
2012-04-06  20268.00
2012-04-07  20268.00
2012-04-08  20268.00
2012-04-09  20412.00
2012-04-10  19998.00
2012-04-11  18999.00
2012-04-12  11465.00
2012-04-13  10975.00
2012-04-14  10975.00
2012-04-15  10975.00
2012-04-16  9750.00
```

I have to apply commission formula to each [pos_sum] value depending on previous available date [cashtrade_sum] value. Results should be added to the current [cashtrade_sum] date. So current date [cashtrade_sum] depends on previous summary or subtraction.

To make things clear, simply how to subtract say 5% of each [pos_sum] value from [cashtrade_sum] where current [pos_sum] is greater than yesterday [cashtrade_sum] or max previous available date. Assuming the value of [cashtrade_sum] has been already modified on a previous step.

Please, help it make on CTE on the fly without INSERTions and separately get the commission values of 5%. Like this:

```
results
-------
                    commission  cash
2012-01-30                      10000.00
2012-03-19                      9868.99
2012-03-20                      9839.02
2012-03-21                      10476.10
2012-03-22          881.4       9594.70
2012-03-23          0.00        9594.70
2012-03-28          0.00        9594.70
2012-03-29          0.00        9594.70
2012-04-03          1041.75     8552.95
2012-04-04          1036.80     7516.12
2012-04-05          1013.40     6502.72
...
```

It is better to fill date gaps as well, but this is just an example. The real formula is far more complex.

Running on SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show what the actual desired results look like? That makes it easier and more interesting to attack the problem rather than reverse engineer a word problem and guess what you expect for output...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so, this was confusing to me. I thought I understood what you were looking for as the following:

> For every given day, the field "cash" is defined as either the value
>   in cashtrade_sum, if present, or a calculated value taking the
>   cashtrade_sum from the last date on record and subtracting all
>   previous commission values. Commission for each date is defined as 5%
>   of the day's pos_sum if the pos_sum is greater than the previous day's
>   cash; otherwise, commission is $0.

But when I actually implemented that, the data doesn't look anything like the example result you provided, because you have cashtrade_sum values for March 23, 28, and 29 that seem to have no reflection in the result. Instead, it seems like as soon as any commission is paid at all, all subsequent entries in cashtrade_bal are ignored and the cash field is only decremented by commission paid.

So, I implemented that instead, not really understanding why. I also added a calendar table to do the date interpolation you mentioned, too, so you get values for every day.

```
CREATE TABLE #cashtrade_sum
(
    recdate date,
    balance money
)

create table #pos_sum
(
    recdate date,
    position money
)

INSERT INTO #cashtrade_sum
VALUES
    ('2012-03-01',  10000.00 ),
    ('2012-03-19',  9868.99 ),
    ('2012-03-20',  9839.02 ),
    ('2012-03-21',  10476.10), 
    ('2012-03-22',  0.00 ),
    ('2012-03-23',  10102.81 ),
    ('2012-03-26',  10314.76 ),
    ('2012-03-27',  11037.40 ),
    ('2012-03-28',  9887.76 ),
    ('2012-03-29',  9234.28 ),
    ('2012-03-30',  8718.67 ),
    ('2012-04-02',  8396.65), 
    ('2012-04-03',  0.00 ),
    ('2012-04-12',  0.00 ),
    ('2012-05-18',  1796.78)

INSERT INTO #pos_sum
VALUES
    ('2012-03-22',  17628.00), 
    ('2012-03-23',  0.00),
    ('2012-03-28',  373.24), 
    ('2012-03-29',  0.00 ),
    ('2012-04-03',  20835.00 ),
    ('2012-04-04',  20736.00 ),
    ('2012-04-05',  20268.00 ),
    ('2012-04-06',  20268.00 ),
    ('2012-04-07',  20268.00 ),
    ('2012-04-08',  20268.00 ),
    ('2012-04-09',  20412.00 ),
    ('2012-04-10',  19998.00 ),
    ('2012-04-11',  18999.00 ),
    ('2012-04-12',  11465.00 ),
    ('2012-04-13',  10975.00 ),
    ('2012-04-14',  10975.00 ),
    ('2012-04-15',  10975.00) ,
    ('2012-04-16',  9750.00)

CREATE TABLE #cal
(
    caldate date
)

DECLARE @CurDate date = '2012-03-01';

while @CurDate < '2012-05-01'
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #cal
    VALUES(@CurDate)

    SELECT @CurDate = DATEADD(day,1,@CurDate)
END

SELECT * FROM #cashtrade_sum;
SELECT * FROM #pos_sum;
SELECT * FROM #cal;

WITH calc AS
(
    SELECT caldate AS calcdate, CAST(0 AS money) AS commission, balance AS dailybal, balance AS runningbal, CAST(0 as money) as position,
        0 as commpaid
    FROM #cal
        left join #cashtrade_sum
            on #cal.caldate = #cashtrade_sum.recdate
    WHERE caldate = (SELECT MIN(caldate) FROM #cal)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT #cal.caldate, 
        comm.commission,
        cts.balance,
        case 
            when prev.commpaid = 1 OR comm.commission > 0 
                then prev.runningbal - comm.commission
            else 
                ISNULL(cts.balance, prev.runningbal - comm.commission) 
        END,
        ps.position,
        CASE WHEN comm.commission > 0 then 1 else prev.commpaid end
    FROM #cal
        outer apply (SELECT * FROM #pos_sum where #cal.caldate = #pos_sum.recdate) ps
        outer apply (SELECT * FROM #cashtrade_sum where #cal.caldate = #cashtrade_sum.recdate) cts
        cross apply (select runningbal, commpaid from calc where calcdate = DATEADD(DAY, -1, #cal.caldate)) prev
        cross apply (select CASE WHEN prev.runningbal < ps.position THEN cast(ps.position * 0.05 as money) ELSE cast(0 as money) END AS commission) comm
)
SELECT calcdate, commission, runningbal FROM calc

drop table #cashtrade_sum
drop table #pos_sum
drop table #cal
```

Note that I changed the first date from January to March because SQL Server has a default recursion limit that will kill this recursive CTE dead after 100 days of data. To make this work for longer time periods, you would need to raise the recursion limit.

I still think either you or I are confused about what the result should actually look like, but this does generate the results you asked for.

Comment: Yes, the technic of fixed date declaration and loop is quite a mess. I found out this one: SELECT ... DATEADD(day, val.number, trd.tradedate) ... FROM ... CROSS JOIN (SELECT number FROM master.dbo.spt_values WHERE 'P' = type AND number <= DATEDIFF(day, (SELECT MIN(tradedate) FROM trades), GETDATE()-1)) AS val

Comment: But I got your idea of CROSS APPLY. Thank you! I'll try on the real data.

Comment: Many many THANKS again! The task sounds odd. I rewrite your solution with more advanced formula and get exactly what I wanted.